# Enabling AWS EventBridge rule from nodejs lambda error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I'm creating Nodejs lambda and trying to set up triggers, one enabled, the other disabled. Then from lambda I attempt to enable disabled trigger but keep getting error:

This is part of SAM template I use to create triggers:

```
AwesomeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub myfunction-${Environment}
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        EnabledTrigger:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(1 hour)
            Enabled: True
        DisabledTrigger:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Name: myrule
            Schedule: rate(1 minute)
            Enabled: False
```

Above creates the triggers that I see from console and one is enabled, the other with name `myrule` disabled as expected. Now this is the code in lambda that attempts to enable `DisabledTrigger`

```
ebevents.activateEventSource({ Name: "myrule" }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success", data.RuleArn);
            }
        });
```

No matter how I name the rule though (currently myrule) I always get this error:

```
Error ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'myrule' at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: aws\.partner(/[\.\-_A-Za-z0-9]+){2,}
```

I'm running out of ideas now and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was using `activateEventSource` but should be `enableRule`, as below:

```
ebevents.enableRule({ Name: "myrule" }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success", data.RuleArn);
            }
        });
```